# Could not create connection from Driver

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g, oracle10g

i am new to the oracle. ,My project is  .net web application which is connected to the oracle database(oracle 11g) when i run my solution in local environment, i get the error in the below line saying that  "Could not create connection from Driver".

```
return factory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection();
```

but this project is working fine in windows XP and I am using windows 7 with oracle 11g installed in my system where i am facing the problem.please can any one give solution.

I understand from the team that this project is designed with oracle 9.2 in mind. how do i make it work in oracle 11g which i have it currently.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use Oracle's [Managed Data Provider for](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) .NET. All your problems with local Oracle installations will go away immediately. Since it's a 100% managed driver, you won't need to install Oracle's client on your machine before connecting to it with .NET programs.

Comment: Hi thanks,i am new to oracle,can u please guide me how do i install managed data provider .please guide me

Comment: You don't even need to install it. Download it from Oracle's website, and put the DLL in your project. That's it.

Comment: hi, sorry to ask you. can you please specify the dll name which i should download and where i should place it? appreciate your quick response!

Comment: You can download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html